# InsertMediaUpload Service BaseUri ArgumentNullException

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I would like to upload a group of files to Google cloud storage in different projects by using C#, however, some of my files uploaded successfully, some of my files threw exceptions saying:"Google Cloud Storage InsertMediaUpload Service BaseUri ArgumentNullException". Does anyone know what caused this error, and how to fix it?
Here is the code I am using:

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
 string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Downloads\csv");    
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            foreach (string path in paths)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    StorageUploader st = new StorageUploader();
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
                    int i = Convert.ToInt32(filename.Substring(8,1));
                    string projectID = "abc" + i.ToString("00");
                    st.StorageUpload(path,pojectID,credentials[i]);
                }));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.Read();
        }
}
```

in StorageUpload(file,projectID, Credential):

```
public void StorageUpload(string filePath,string project,StorageService aService)
        {
            var filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);


            var projectName = project;
            var num = projectName.Substring(14,1);
            var bucketToUpload = "myBucket" + num;
            var newObject = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object()
            {
                Bucket = bucketToUpload,
                Name = filename
            };

            FileStream fileStream = null;
            try
            {

                fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                fileStream.Position = 0;          
                var uploadRequest = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.ObjectsResource.InsertMediaUpload(aService, newObject,
                bucketToUpload, fileStream, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
               uploadRequest.UploadAsync();
               var stats = uploadRequest.GetProgress().Status;
               while (true)
               {
                   if (uploadRequest.GetProgress().Status.ToString() == "Completed")
                   {

                       return;

                   }
                   else if (uploadRequest.GetProgress().Status.ToString() == "Failed")
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(filename + uploadRequest.GetProgress().Exception.ToString());
                   }
                   Console.WriteLine("Wait");
                   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

               }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (fileStream != null)
                {

                    fileStream.Dispose();
                }
            }

        }
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There is still no answer for this problems? By the way, the google cloud API has already been enabled. I have searched online, there seems no correct answer for this question.